# How to authorize websocket connection with socket.io?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, websocket, socket.io, authorization

I use ReactJS and I try establish connection with NodeJS, and for http requests I use session based authentication. But once I try connect from client to server websocket I just can't access that cookie or find a way to check if it's user that connects.

tried printing whole socket.request and I didn't see any client cookies provided in there.

reactjs:

```
setSocket(io(serverUrl));
```

nodejs:

```
const configureSocketIO = (server: any): Server => {
console.log("io initialized")
const io = new Server(server, {
cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000', 
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
  },

});

io.engine.use(session({
secret: SERVER_SECRET as string,
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: true,
cookie: { secure: true }
}));

io.use((socket, next) => {

console.log(socket.request)
next();
});


return io;
};
```